# NSOutlineView does not allow expansion

Tags: cocoa

I have a simple NSOutlineView, init via swift, with 2 columns. I made the following very simple data source, hoping to test it this way, but maybe I this format is not allowable. I assume the table view only queries as needed, so that this won't cause an infinite loop.

The result is a 4 row, 2 column table layout with "Name" and "Value", but no expansion buttons.

I've implemented isExpandable as mentioned in the Obj-C post with similar name and added the columns.

Is there something more that I need to do to setup a NSOutlineView with expandable elements, or should I attempt another more realistic dataSource test:

```
import Cocoa

class OutlineDataSource : NSObject,NSOutlineViewDataSource
{
    var a = "Name"
    var b = "Value"

    var column1 : NSTableColumn
    var column2 : NSTableColumn

    init(column1:NSTableColumn,column2:NSTableColumn) {
        self.column1 = column1
        self.column2 = column2
    }

    func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, numberOfChildrenOfItem item: AnyObject?) -> Int
    {
        return 4;
    }

    func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, child index: Int, ofItem item: AnyObject?) -> AnyObject
    {
        return a
    }

    func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, isItemExpandable item: AnyObject) -> Bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, objectValueForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, byItem item: AnyObject?) -> AnyObject?
    {
        if (tableColumn == column1)
        {
            return a
        }
        return b
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

outlineTableColumn needs to be set on the outline view.

Comment: This is absolutely an essential part of making NSOutlineView work and the Apple documentation gives it no attention on their NSOutlineView page. They go on about the view delegate and dataSource. At least when programmatically creating an NSOutlineView, along with the dataSource, and the NSTableColumn(s), setting this is critical - more critical than setting the delegate (which I've left nil and can see it still works). Again, the symptom is missing triangles and no way to expand the items that are visible from the root level. This was the correct answer for my case.

Comment: Not only do you need to `setOutlineTableColumn`, you must also add it, using `addTableColumn`. Only calling 1 of these results in the view elements not being visible.